# Identifying files which were created on my local system at a certain date, despite "Date created" metadata retained from installer

Tags: windows-10, metadata, date, file-attributes

I've installed a program, and all the files the installer created have identical "date created" and "date modified" metadata, indicating the date that the file was last modified by the software's creator. This information would be correct for the files used to create the installation package, but is technically not correct for the copies of these files on my computer, since those copies did not exist an hour ago.

This creates a problem when I'm attempting to manually identify what exactly this program has installed - e.g. whether it's created any files outside of its own installation directory.

There are a few possible solutions I can envision, though I don't know how to accomplish any of them:

- Can I search for files by the date and time that they were first created on the computer I am using, rather than the date in their metadata? For instance, the date and time their record in the NTFS file table was created.
- Can I view a chronological list of recent actions which Windows performed, which would include creation and copying of files?
- Failing that, can I cause Windows to record this date for all files created on my computer's drives, or copied to them, in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Since at least part of your goal is, "whether it's created any files outside of its own installation directory," then  you could run the installation app in a virtual environment, e.g., [*Sandboxie*](https://sandboxie-plus.com/sandboxie/), which can be configured to create any adjunct files that might be in other locations than the executable's, such as *Program Data* or *Program Files/Common files*, in synonymous folders in the *Sandboxie* directory structure.

These files can then be deleted, or the files could be moved by *Sandboxie* to their intended locations.

This should make clear any file changes, as well as Registry changes, made by the installation app. Nirsoft's [RegistryChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html) is another tool to diff the Registry before/after installation.